# Cross origin iframe, Safari-only issue

Tags: javascript, https, safari, cross-domain

On domain www.maindomain.com I have the following page

```
<iframe src='https://www.otherdomain.com/somepage.php' />
```

The IIS webserver that hosts www.otherdomain.com has been properly configured with the necessary cross-origin headers.

In fact, there's no issue with any of the major browsers, desktop and mobile.
However, on Safari and on Safari only, the connection is rejected as insecure.

Is there a known workaround?
Thanks

Comment: Why it is being rejected as insecure? Does the iframe element appear in a page served over plain HTTP? Don't do that, use SSL too. Is there a problem with "otherdomain's" (please use example.com/net/org for example URIs) certificate? Get them to fix the certificate.

Comment: www.maindomain.com is served through plain http.  www.otherdomain.com is server over https. There are no issues with the certificate. In fact there are no issues with anything but Safari.

Comment: Don't mix secure and insecure content. Use SSL throughout.

Comment: It's not by design, that I am mixing secure and insecure content. One server belongs to a customer who doesn't want to maintain certificates. The other server belongs to me, and it's equipped with certificates. This is why I chose the term "workaround" rather than "solution". The solution would be: get the customer to buy a certificate. A workaround would work... around.... the problem with Safari.